# Convert ipv6 to integer and open in browser

Tags: ip, ipv6

It's common practice to convert ip addresses, ipv4 in particular, to integer values (`95.191.162.12` becomes `160639438`). With ipv4 I can open the integer value in my browser (by typing `http(or whatever)://160639438`), and it will perfectly work.

I tried the same with ipv6: `http://[2a00:1450:4011:804::1001]` works, but its integer representation `55827987829239171056733755306672132097` does not (I tried opening `http://[55827987829239171056733755306672132097]`, `http://55827987829239171056733755306672132097`, `[55827987829239171056733755306672132097]:80`, etc.).

Is there any way to address ipv6 host by its integer value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC3493](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3493.txt) Section 6.3 suggests that the pure-integer form of IP address which is valid in `inet_addr()` is no longer acceptable in the equivalent function `inet_pton()` for IPv6. Quote:

> The inet_pton() function does not accept other formats (such as the
>      octal numbers, hexadecimal numbers, and fewer than four numbers that
>      inet_addr() accepts).